# With an HTML file, is it possible to keep the user on the same page upon pressing submit? jQuery and/or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html

On the following page: http://christianselig.com/contact.html I want to have it so when they click Send Message, it will send the message using PHP and keep them on the same page, perhaps changing the submit button to a success message.

Is this possible with PHP and jQuery?

Comment: It is, using AJAX. Read more on how to send request with jQuery.post() then show some code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use [`Ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to submit the form and then use [DOM manipulating functionality](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Manipulation) to update your page.

Answer (score 2):

Look at using ajax to submit the page

```
$.ajax({
        cache: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: { name: $('#Name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), message: $('#Message').val()  },
        url: "/controller/sendMessage",
        success: function (msg) {
            //do something

        }
    });
```

Make sure your controller doesn't respond with a response, just pass a Json wrapped Success message back

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, one of two ways in my experience.

1. You can of course use AJAX, which will make it a lot more smooth for the user, but of course is a little harder.
2. If you don't mind the user reloading the page, then you would add a `action="./contact.html?submit=true`, which would simply reload the page, and then you make the form check if the `submit` variable is set in the `$_GET` global variable.

Hope this helps. :) (Sorry if this belongs in the comments, I can't actually post in the comments of the main page for some reason.)